# Arguments with Browserify modules

Tags: javascript, module, browserify

I use modules with Browserify like this :

```
module.exports = (function() {

'use strict';

    var hide = function(elementId) {

        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.style.opacity = 0;

    };

    return hide;

}());
```

As i use 'document' in my module, should I go into argument like this ?

Idem for document, window, navigator, XMLHttpRequest

```
module.exports = (function(document) {

    ...

}(document));
```

Whatever the answer, can you explain why?

Comment: If you have two questions it is probably better to ask also two separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Browserify wraps each module in a function for you. There is no advantage in the extra wrapper. Passing document or whatever global as an argument does not win anything either. You can write browser modules as if they where node modules. Just think of each file as one large function that gets invoked on the first `require`.

Answer (score 1):

So I write this directly :

```
module.exports = function(elementId) {

    'use strict';

    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.opacity = 0;

}
```

And if I want to return an object with many public methods (revealing module pattern), I have to proceed this way ? And I have to pass document?

```
module.exports = (function() {

    var on = function() {

    };

    var off = function() {

    };

    return {
        on: on,
        off: off
    };

})();
```